# Jquery light switch setting starting state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using this setup to show if light is turned on or off:

http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/11/jquery-light-switch-on-off-using-css3.html

How can i choose wich switch state to start?

As of now I have a lightvalue in my database, 1 = on 0 = off. I use sql to retrieve this value and load the appropriate light bulb.

But how would i do this with the switch? I don't have switch1 and switch2 so i can load the one i want based on lightvalue.

here is the code:

```
light.js

var lightVal = document.getElementById("light-bulb2");

    function getLightValue(r) {
        var lightValue;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Database/checklight.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {room: r},
            success: function(data) {
                data1 = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(data1, function(key, val) {
                    lightValue = val.light;
                    lightVal.style.opacity = lightValue;
                });

            },
            async: false
        });


    }

    function updateLight(val, rom) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Database/updateLight.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {light: val, room: room},
            success: function(data) {
                data2 = JSON.parse(data);
                if (data2 < 1) {
                    alert("Not Updated");
                }
            },
            async: false

        });
    }

    light.php

    <div id="temptre">
                    <div id="light-bulb" class="off ui-draggable" >
                        <div id="light-bulb2" style="opacity: 0">
                            <script src="JS/light.js">
                            </script>
                        </div></div>
                    <div class="cube-switch">
                        <span class="switch">
                            <span class="switch-state off">Off</span>
                            <span class="switch-state on">On</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>               
                </div>



                <script>

                    getLightValue(<?php echo $_SESSION['sess_room']; ?>);

                    $('.cube-switch .switch').click(function() {
                        if ($('.cube-switch').hasClass('active')) {
                            $('.cube-switch').removeClass('active');
                            $('#light-bulb2').css({'opacity': '0'});
                            updateLight(0, <?php echo $_SESSION['sess_room']; ?>);

                        } else {
                            $('.cube-switch').addClass('active');
                            $('#light-bulb2').css({'opacity': '1'});
                            updateLight(1, <?php echo $_SESSION['sess_room']; ?>);
                        }
                    });

                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make switch work, then you need to trigger the `click` event, so that it can be switch on and off (based on value).

```
// call(trigger) click event on success
function updateLight(val, rom) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Database/updateLight.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            light: val,
            room: room
        },
        success: function (data) {
            data2 = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data == 1) {
                $('.cube-switch .switch').trigger('click', [{
                    forceStart: true
                }]);
            } else {
                $('.cube-switch .switch').trigger('click', [{
                    forceStart: false
                }]);
            }
        },
        async: false

    });
}


// change your click event to handle the passed argument
$('.cube-switch .switch').click(function (e, data) {
    if (typeof data !== 'undefined') {
        if (data.forceStart) {
            // remove the active class, so that it can add the active class later to match switch on
            $('.cube-switch').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.cube-switch').addClass('active')
        }
    }
    if ($('.cube-switch').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.cube-switch').removeClass('active');
        $('#light-bulb2').css({
            'opacity': '0'
        });
        updateLight(0, <? php echo $_SESSION['sess_room']; ?> );

    } else {
        $('.cube-switch').addClass('active');
        $('#light-bulb2').css({
            'opacity': '1'
        });
        updateLight(1, <? php echo $_SESSION['sess_room']; ?> );
    }
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4rkQZ/152/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with php, but give div.cube-switch a class of 'active' if it's on, and remove the inline opacity style (tidy up the php by all means!)

```
<div href="" class="cube-switch <?php if ($on) { echo ' active'; } ?>">
    <span class="switch">
        <span class="switch-state off">Off</span>
        <span class="switch-state on">On</span>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="light-bulb" class="off ui-draggable">
    <div id="light-bulb2" <?php if (!$on) { echo 'style="opacity:0"'; } ?>></div>
</div>
```